# Appcelerator: Use GCM to get a notification, have that notification open the app

Tags: android, titanium, google-cloud-messaging

I've got GCM sending notifications to my phone, and my phone can get them (if the app has already been opened. If it's no longer running, it doesn't open. That's also a problem.)

However, right now I'm focusing on what happens when I click on a notification that I've received. In particular, nothing happens. I've got it set up so that it should open up the app, via intents, but it's not working.

Here's the relevant portion from my app.js:

```
var senderId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

var c2dm = require('com.findlaw.c2dm');
Ti.API.info("module is => " + c2dm);

Ti.API.info('Registering...');
c2dm.registerC2dm(senderId, {
    success:function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('JS registration success event: ' + e.registrationId);

        var params = {devicecode: e.registrationId, deviceType: "Android"};
        JOURNAL.webApi.webCallPOST(JOURNAL.serviceLocatorModel.urls.Membership, "/registerdevice", params, JOURNAL.registerDeviceComplete, JOURNAL.registerDeviceError);
    },
    error:function(e) {
        Ti.API.error("Error during registration: "+e.error);

        var message;
        if(e.error == "ACCOUNT_MISSING") {
            message = "No Google account found; you'll need to add one (in Settings/Accounts) in order to activate notifications";
        } else {
            message = "Error during registration: "+e.error
        }

        Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title: 'Push Notification Setup',
            message: message,
            buttonNames: ['OK']
        }).show();
    },
    callback:function(e) // called when a push notification is received
    {
        Ti.API.info('JS message event: ' + JSON.stringify(e.data));

        var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
            flags: Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED,
            className: 'com.geneca.journaling.GenecaJournalingActivity',
            //className: 'org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity',
            packageName: 'com.geneca.journaling'
        });
        intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        // This is fairly static: Not much need to be altered here
        var pending = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
            activity: Ti.Android.currentActivity,
            intent: intent,
            type: Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
        });

        var notification = Ti.Android.createNotification({
            contentIntent: pending,
            contentTitle: 'New message',
            contentText: e.data.message,
            tickerText: "New message"
        });

        Ti.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
});
```

And here's the relevant portion from my tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <activity android:name="com.geneca.journaling.GenecaJournalingActivity" />
        <permission android:name="com.geneca.journaling.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.geneca.journaling.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <application>
            <service android:name="com.findlaw.c2dm.C2DMReceiver"/>
            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" 
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                    <category android:name="com.geneca.journaling"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                    <category android:name="com.geneca.journaling"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
<modules>
    <module platform="android" version="0.1">com.findlaw.c2dm</module>
</modules>
```

I've run log cat, and it's getting the notification, and the intent, but it spits this out, and doesn't open the app:

```
I/ActivityManager(  307): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=com.geneca.journaling cmp=com.geneca.journaling/.GenecaJournalingActivity bnds=[0,102][720,230] u=0} from pid -1
W/KeyguardViewMediator(  307): verifyUnlock called when not externally disabled
W/InputMethodManagerService(  307): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41c18038 attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@42319798
```

(The middle one doesn't always show up, so I don't think it's really relevant.)

On a side note, if the app isn't open, the log cat gives me `Bad notification posted from package com.geneca.journaling.mobile: Couldn't create icon` and then a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have upload my gcm module to github. Hope you guys can work with it fine. =] https://github.com/liccowee/Google-Cloud-Messaging--Titanium-

Comment: @licco wee, I have include the module and worked with example PushNofication.js file. But after getting "Registering.." log, i am not getting anything like success log/alert , error log/alert.